# Groupby count on unique date time in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Doctor   Start                B_ID  Session      Finish                 NoShow
    A   2020-01-18 12:00:00     1    S1         2020-01-18 12:33:00     no
    A   2020-01-18 12:20:00     2    S1         2020-01-18 12:52:00     no
    A   2020-01-18 13:00:00     3    S1         2020-01-18 13:23:00     no
    A   2020-01-18 13:00:00     4    S1         2020-01-18 13:37:00     yes
    A   2020-01-18 13:35:00     5    S1         2020-01-18 13:56:00     no
    A   2020-01-18 14:10:00     6    S1         2020-01-18 14:15:00     no
    A   2020-01-18 14:10:00     7    S1         2020-01-18 14:28:00     yes
    A   2020-01-18 14:10:00     8    S1         2020-01-18 14:40:00     yes
    A   2020-01-18 14:10:00     9    S1         2020-01-18 15:01:00     no
    A   2020-01-19 12:00:00    12    S2         2020-01-19 12:20:00     no
    A   2020-01-19 12:30:00    13    S2         2020-01-19 12:40:00     no
    A   2020-01-19 13:00:00    14    S2         2020-01-19 13:20:00     yes
    A   2020-01-19 13:40:00    15    S2         2020-01-19 13:46:00     no
    A   2020-01-19 14:00:00    16    S2         2020-01-19 14:10:00     yes
    A   2020-01-19 14:00:00    17    S2         2020-01-19 14:20:00     no
    A   2020-01-19 14:00:00    19    S2         2020-01-19 14:40:00     yes
    B   2020-01-18 12:00:00    21    S3         2020-01-18 12:33:00     no
    B   2020-01-18 12:30:00    22    S3         2020-01-18 12:52:00     no
    B   2020-01-18 13:10:00    23    S3         2020-01-18 13:25:00     no
    B   2020-01-18 13:10:00    24    S3         2020-01-18 13:39:00     no
    B   2020-01-18 13:30:00    25    S3         2020-01-18 13:56:00     yes
    B   2020-01-18 14:05:00    26    S3         2020-01-18 14:15:00     no
    B   2020-01-18 14:30:00    27    S3         2020-01-18 14:48:00     yes
```

From the above I would like to prepare below data frame

Expected Output:

```
Doctor        Day       No_of_slots    No_of_bookings    No_of_NoShow
A         2020-01-18        5               9               3    
A         2020-01-19        5               7               3  
b         2020-01-18        6               7               2
```

Where

```
 No_of_slots = Total number of slots based on unique Start time

 No_of_bookings = Total number of bookings 

 No_of_NoShow = Number of NoShow == 'yes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregation, for count `yes` values is used `sum` by helper column `new` created by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and converting to numeric by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'])

d = df['Start'].dt.date.rename('Day')
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['NoShow'].eq('yes').view('i1'))
         .groupby(['Doctor', d]).agg(No_of_slots=('Start','nunique'),
                                     No_of_bookings=('Start','size'),
                                     No_of_NoShow=('new', 'sum'))
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Doctor         Day  No_of_slots  No_of_bookings  No_of_NoShow
0      A  2020-01-18            5               9             3
1      A  2020-01-19            5               7             3
2      B  2020-01-18            6               7             2
```

Comment: pls look into this question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441460/create-new-rows-based-the-values-of-one-of-the-column-in-pandas

Comment: @ALI - It seems is necessary some loopy solution, really complicated. And loopy solutions in pandas are not easy... I try something but still cannot create solution. Sorry :(